# How to make Two queries run in the same connection

Tags: sql, asp.net

Currently trying to run these two queries in the same connection with the goal of having a cut and not cut result side by side (will be 10 more like this).
Currently running into the attached error, do I need to create them all as sub queries, if so how would I go around this?

Beginner programmer so apologies if this doesn't make much sense or seems simple

```
    set connJobIndex=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    set rsJobs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    connJobIndex.open Application("connJobIndex_Orders")
    
    
    
    
    strSQL="    SELECT    TOP 1    sum(Production.Quantity) over (partition by Production.Quantity order by Production.Quantity) as wip_70mm "
    strSQL=strSQL&" FROM            Heading INNER JOIN "
    strSQL=strSQL&"                 Production ON Heading.JobKeyID = Production.JobKeyID INNER JOIN "
    strSQL=strSQL& "                Tracking ON Production.JobKeyID = Tracking.JobKeyID AND Production.ItemKeyID = Tracking.ItemKeyID "
    strSQL=strSQL& " WHERE        (dbo.Production.ProductID IN (13, 18, 42, 43, 14, 152, 162, 155, 157, 156, 153, 163, 168, 167, 164)) and DateDelivery between '" & datestring & "' and '" & datestringEnd & "'"
    strSQL=strSQL& " GROUP BY   Production.JobKeyID, Production.ItemKeyID, Production.Quantity "
    strSQL=strSQL& " HAVING        (MAX(Tracking.StageID) >= 110 and max(stageid) < 200 )  "
    
    
    
    strSQL="            SELECT  count(*) as NotCut_70mm "
    strSQL=strSQL& "    FROM            Heading INNER JOIN "
    strSQL=strSQL& "                            Production ON Heading.JobKeyID = Production.JobKeyID LEFT JOIN "
    strSQL=strSQL& "                            Tracking ON Production.JobKeyID = Tracking.JobKeyID AND Production.ItemKeyID = Tracking.ItemKeyID "
    strSQL=strSQL& "    WHERE        (dbo.Production.ProductID IN (13, 18, 42, 43, 14, 152, 162, 155, 157, 156, 153, 163, 168, 167, 164)) and  DateDelivery between '" & datestring & "' and '" & datestringEnd & "'"
    strSQL=strSQL& "    GROUP BY tracking.JobKeyID "
    strSQL=strSQL& "    HAVING (max(stageid) <110 or max(stageid) IS NULL)   "
    
    
    
    
    rsjobs.Open strSQL,connJobIndex

    response.write "<table>"
        response.write "<tr>"
        response.write "<th class=BordersAll>" 
        response.write "70mm"
        response.write "</TH>"
        response.write "</TH>"
        response.write "<th class=BordersAll>" 
        response.write "70mm NotCut"
        response.write "</TH>"
        response.write "</TR>"
        
        
        
        
        
    do until rsJobs.EOF
        with Response
        .write "<tr>"
        .write "<th class=BordersAll>" 
        .write rsjobs("wip_70mm")
        .write rsjobs("NotCut_70mm")
        .write "</TH>"
        .write "</TR>"
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhVVt.png

Answer (score 0):

resolved it

```
strSQL="    (SELECT    TOP 1    sum(Production.Quantity) over (partition by Production.Quantity order by Production.Quantity) as wip_70mm "
    strSQL=strSQL&" FROM            Heading INNER JOIN "
    strSQL=strSQL&"                 Production ON Heading.JobKeyID = Production.JobKeyID INNER JOIN "
    strSQL=strSQL& "                Tracking ON Production.JobKeyID = Tracking.JobKeyID AND Production.ItemKeyID = Tracking.ItemKeyID "
    strSQL=strSQL& " WHERE        (dbo.Production.ProductID IN (13, 18, 42, 43, 14, 152, 162, 155, 157, 156, 153, 163, 168, 167, 164)) and DateDelivery between '" & datestring & "' and '" & datestringEnd & "'"
    strSQL=strSQL& " GROUP BY   Production.JobKeyID, Production.ItemKeyID, Production.Quantity "
    strSQL=strSQL& " HAVING        (MAX(Tracking.StageID) >= 110 and max(stageid) < 200 )) as wip_70mm , "
    
    
    
    strSQL=strSQL&"         (SELECT  count(*) as NotCut_70mm "
    strSQL=strSQL& "    FROM            Heading INNER JOIN "
    strSQL=strSQL& "                            Production ON Heading.JobKeyID = Production.JobKeyID LEFT JOIN "
    strSQL=strSQL& "                            Tracking ON Production.JobKeyID = Tracking.JobKeyID AND Production.ItemKeyID = Tracking.ItemKeyID "
    strSQL=strSQL& "    WHERE        (dbo.Production.ProductID IN (13, 18, 42, 43, 14, 152, 162, 155, 157, 156, 153, 163, 168, 167, 164)) and  DateDelivery between '" & datestring & "' and '" & datestringEnd & "'"
    strSQL=strSQL& "    GROUP BY tracking.JobKeyID "
    strSQL=strSQL& "    HAVING (max(stageid) <110 or max(stageid) IS NULL)) as NotCut_70mm "
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.